# when I added this ng add @angular/pwa and i get error in angular version 14

Tags: angular14

When I add `ng add @angular/pwa` package to the angular project, I given an error. Tried to delete node modules and re-install but that did not resolve

> Failed to generate service worker - Cannot find package '@angular/service-worker'

[image]